# Knockout. How to determine what observable variable is subscribed?

Tags: knockout.js

If I have a lot of variables that are knockout **observable** object. Is there any simple way to determine what variable is **subscribed**? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native function `isObservable()`:

```
let myVar1 = ko.observable('value');
let myVar2 = 'value';
console.log(ko.isObservable(myVar1)); //true
console.log(ko.isObservable(myVar2)); //false
```

Comment: Oh,that's a good tips. But what I want was to determine subscribed observable. For example: let bar = ko.observable('bar'); bar.subscribe(()=>{}); if (bar.isSubscibed()) {do 
 something};

Comment: Ok, you can use myVal1.getSubscriptionsCount()

Comment: Thx Bludev.I have tried getSubscriptionsCount. It's working fine when an observable variable wasn't related with html. But when you related with html you can still get result from getSubscriptionsCount even though you aren't subscribed a variable. For example, html: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>, vm: name : ko.observable("Mike"), and execute: name.getSubscriptionsCount(), and result: 1.